# php html mail not working on cpanel server

Tags: php, html, email, cpanel

I have a code to send html mail with php on cpanel but doesn't send without any errors. I have tested plain text mail and that is working fine, but once I add the header like below, it doesn't work.

```
//send html mail
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'info@toludimaokojie.com');
            $headers = "From: info@toludimaokojie.com\r\n"."X-Mailer: php";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        $html = '<html> 
   <body>
  <h2>Result Analysis for Test With Reference Number:'.$reference.'</h2>
  <br/>
  <p><b>Personality: '.$personality_mail.'</b></p>
  <br/>
  <p><b>MBQ Score: '.$resultTotal.'</b></p>
  <br/>
  <ul>'.$analyseData.'</ul>
  <pre>Mail Sent on '.date("l, F Y H:i:sa").'</pre>
  </body>
  </html>';                          
  mail("olaegbesamuel@gmail.com", "MBQ TEST ANALYSIS", $html, $headers);
```

This doesn't work. Please help, i guess am doing everything correctly here. I have tested without html and confirmed that `mail` is working

Comment: _...but doesn't send without any errors..._ What errors?

Comment: It doesn't give any error as to why it is not sending

Comment: Still no answer to this...

Answer (score 0):

You have defined $headers with all mandatory email parameters but look at your `$header` variable, there are two things need to be changed,

1) You have used $header and $headers both so use either of them and append them to one variable. 
2) your 2nd line of $header variable is missing `.` to append the previous header values, so the corrected code should be:

```
         $headers = "From: info@toludimaokojie.com\r\n"."X-Mailer: php";
         $headers .= "From: $from\r\n"; 
         $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
```

As you missed `.` operator in 2nd line, it will remove `From` header and so it would not be sending email.
Try after changing these lines.

Comment: Oh...the headers/header was a mistake and I have corrected that and the mail still doesn't send

Comment: Are you trying to send email from `localhost` ?

Comment: Of course not. I mentioned cpanel in my question. Its definitely on a host. The mail function works when there is no header given in the mail function parameter

Comment: Actually I dont know for what we should use `X-Mailer: php` I just checked W3schools and it has simpler headers set with the code snippet. [Here you go](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

Comment: Alright. That doesn't work as well.

Comment: Can you go to cPanel log to see? I am sure there must be some log about the issue.

Comment: There is no log concerning `mail()` not working